# Erlang: parallel accumulator

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang, pid

I am working on an Erlang method that is to perform a parallelized version of an accumulator. The method is to take an associative and commutative operator, as well a list of values, and then return the answer by applying the operator to the values in the list. The following two examples show the command line I/O of the program:

Example 1

```
CL Input: sum(fun (A,B) -> A++B end , ["U", "V", "W"]).
CL Output: "UVW"
```

Example 2

```
CL Input: sum(fun(A,B) -> A+B end, [2,6,7,10,12]
CL Output: 37
```

This is the code I have so far. My question is, how would I go about changing this method to fit the above examples, as well as produce the correct result, in parallel?

```
reduceFunc(Func, [Acc]) -> Acc;
    reduceFunc(Func, List) ->
       { L, R } = lists:split(trunc(length(List)/2), List),
        Pids = self(),
        io:format("Distribute processes~n"),
        Pl = spawn(fun() -> reduceFunc(Pids, L) end),
        Pr = spawn(fun() -> reduceFunc(Pids, R) end),
        Func(Pl, Pr).
```

The code is returning an arithmetic expression error when evaluating the operator (e.g., +/2), and then gives the PIDs of each without the numeric value and operator applied, such as this...

```
Error in process <0.100.0> with exit value:
{{badfun,<0.95.0>},
```

I have been trying to approach this in a similar way as a merge sort or another divide and conquer algorithm, but I do not know where the code should be revised from this point.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistake, I will list below:

```
Pl = spawn(fun() -> reduceFunc(Pids, L) end),
Pr = spawn(fun() -> reduceFunc(Pids, R) end)
```

1. You defined function reduceFunc/2 with first arg is a ***FUNC***, but you put PID (here in your example <0.95.0>), so your machine dump error.
2. You spawn slave process but not return result to master process. `spawn` function always return PID of slave process, not return result of your function. You should define send and receive result for you master and slave process.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out one way to answer this.

I had to parallelize a serial program I had written to make it more efficient.

In the example below:

1. Divide the list in half;
2. Send the two halves to be processed simultaneously by other processes;
3. Wait for their return;
4. Apply the appropriate reduction operation to the two halves.

```erlang
    -module(erlang2).
    -compile(export_all).
    -export([reduce/2]).

    reduce(Func, List) ->
        reduce(root, Func, List).

    %When done send results to Parent
    reduce(Parent, _, [A]) -> 
        %send to parent 
        Parent ! { self(), A}; 

    %get contents of list, apply function and store in Parent
    reduce(Parent, Func, List) ->
                { Left, Right } = lists:split(trunc(length(List)/2), List),
                Me = self(),
                %io:format("Splitting in two~n"),
                Pl = spawn(fun() -> reduce(Me, Func, Left) end),
                Pr = spawn(fun() -> reduce(Me, Func, Right) end),
                %merge results in parent and call Func on final left and right halves
                combine(Parent, Func,[Pl, Pr]).

    %merge pl and pl and combine in parent
    combine(Parent, Func, [Pl, Pr]) ->
        %wait for processes to complete (using receive) and then send to Parent
        receive
            { Pl, Sorted } -> combine(Parent, Func, Pr, Sorted);
            { Pr, Sorted } -> combine(Parent, Func, Pl, Sorted)
        end.

    combine(Parent, Func, P, List) ->
        %wait and store in results and then call ! to send
        receive
            { P, Sorted } ->
                Results = Func(Sorted, List),
                case Parent of
                    root ->
                        Results;
                    %send results to parent
                    _ -> Parent ! {self(), Results}
                end
        end.
```

Comment: Hi reverb1010, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you describe your code example in your answer a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, so basically this was a coding project I was working on to parallelize a serial program I had written to make it more efficient. In the code above, my thought was process was to 1.) Divide the list in half;
2.) Send the two halves to be processed simultaneously by other processes 3) Wait for their return; 4) Apply the appropriate reduction operation to the two halves.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your comment into your answer to make it obvious for the asker, and anyone else who finds this question later.